# Hazelcast - Locks acquired on distributed map are NOT shown in management center

Tags: java, locking, distributed-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to evaluate hazelcast for distributed lock solution.

I am creating a  hazelcast client instance from my application. Then I am acquiring lock over map using IMap.tryLock method. During debug and from logs I am seeing that I could acquire the lock successfully.

After successful lock acquisition I am putting an entry to map.

So at that time instant there is one entry and one lock in the map.

In management center, I can see that there is only one entry in the map  but can not see the lock.

[image]

Is this the expected behaviour? If this is the expected behaviour what does locks mean for maps in management center?

Comment: Don't use hazelcast for anything requiring consistency https://jepsen.io/analyses/hazelcast-3-8-3

Answer (score 0):

It's not the expected behaviour. I have tried your scenario with Hazelcast 3.9.1 and Management Center 3.9.1, it shows the lock count correctly.

[image: Management Center Map Screen showing lock count correctly]

Which version of Hazelcast and Management Center are you using? I would advise checking if `tryLock` returns `true` - you might not be acquiring the lock correctly.